# Regex match commas after a closing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, split

In Javascript, I am trying to split the following string

```
var s1 = "(-infinity, -3],(-3,-2),[1,infinity)";
```

into an array

```
["(-infinity, -3]","(-3,-2)","[1,infinity)"]
```

by using this statement

```
s1.split(/(?=[\]\)]),/);
```

to explain, I want to split the string by commas that follow a closing square bracket or parenthesis. I use the Look Ahead `(?=[\]\)]),` to do so, but it doesn't match any commas. When I change it to `(?![\]\)]),`, it matches every commas. Please suggest what is the problem in my regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. `(?=...)` is a look-ahead group, not a look-behind. This means that `s1.split(/(?=[\]\)]),/);` matches only if the next character is simultaneously `]` or `)` and `,`, which is impossible.

Try this instead:

```
s1.split(/,(?=[\[\(])/);
```

Comment: This is because I misunderstand the words. I thought "look ahead" means to look to the left hand side and "look behind" to look to the right, :p. Thank you very much.